# how to convert multiple columns in a data frame into a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I've a DataFrame which contains the data for different students going to school. It has different columns like `rank`, `major_code`, `major`, `unemployed` etc.

I used `df.values` (in this case `recent_grads.values`) to Return a numpy representation of the DataFrame.

```
recent_grads_np = recent_grads.values
print(recent_grads_np)
```

This works as `d.values` changes the entire DataFrame into Numpy array. The result is this:

```
[[1 2419 'PETROLEUM ENGINEERING' ... 1534 364 193]
 [2 2416 'MINING AND MINERAL ENGINEERING' ... 350 257 50]
 [3 2415 'METALLURGICAL ENGINEERING' ... 456 176 0]
 ...
 [172 5203 'COUNSELING PSYCHOLOGY' ... 2403 1245 308]
 [173 3501 'LIBRARY SCIENCE' ... 288 338 192]]
```

**How do I select only a few columns from the entire Dataframe and then convert into a numpy array ?**

Comment: my_array = df['Column Name'].values

Answer (score 4):

You should easily use ".values" at the end of your Dataframe and it will give you your numpy array.

To select specific dataframe columns, you can say df[["A","B","C"]] where "A", "B", and "C" are your columns names.

So:
df[["A","B","C"]].values

will give you what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I also needed something similar, and I found the following approach.
You can also use the apply function with lambda.
Thus, you can create your own type of array and even convert the data, like this:

```
raw_converted_data = df[["A", "B", "C"]].apply(lambda x: [x["A"], x["B"], x["C"]], axis=1)

list(raw_converted_data)
```

In this example, the first line will return the data separated into an array. Then, in the second line, this data becomes a list.

I hope this answer helps someone else also looking for this.